# Which authentication methods are safe on unsecured HTTP channel?

Tags: security, http, session, authentication, protocols

Does there exist any authentication protocol which is safe on unsecured channel? Session id's are easily hijacked by MitM, so which mechanism are used to make the session secure on unsecured HTTP channel?

Comment: I guess that _unsecured HTTP channel_ is a channel without SSL? So there're no such methods.

Answer (score 1):

For HTTP Following Authentication Schemes are useful.

1. Basic [rfc:7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617)
2. Bearer [rfc:6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750)
3. Digest [rfc:7616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616)
4. HOBA [rfc:7486](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7486) refer section 3
5. Mutual [rfc:8120](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8120)
6. AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 [aws:docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html)

Also a good detail explanation could be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication)

Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating against a server over HTTP is problematic as without a server certificate, you can't be sure you are actually communicating with the intended server. Also, any credentials being sent to the server are susceptible to eaves-dropping.

Having said that, there are authentication protocols that can be used securely over HTTP once the server and client have exchanged a secret over a secure channel. Protocols like [Hawk](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk) or [AWS signatures](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) do not require HTTPS for every subsequent request.